# update record without refreshing/leaving page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've a PHP-page with a table in it.

The table is populated with records from a MySQL-database.
One field of a table (housing) can contain two values: `0` and `1`.

When a student is `housed` the value of the field is 1 otherwise 0.
In the table I want to use a **JQUERY UI-button** with O/I (like a switch).

When the button is clicked, the value needs to be updated in the MySQL-table and there should an icon `("checked")` be shown right to the JQUERY UI-button, if the value is 1 else the icon should disappear.

I assume I need ajax to do this?
Can anyone tell me if this can be done or not? And perhaps how it can be done?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes it can be done

an example here http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

which says

> 1. Create a php script called api.php on your server
> 2. Copy and paste the example below and save it:

```
<?php 

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";

  $databaseName = "ajax01";
  $tableName = "variables";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

then

> 1. Create a html script called client.php in the same directory with the following content in it:

```
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example client script for JQUERY:AJAX -> PHP:MYSQL example
---------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1) Create some html content that can be accessed by jquery
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <h2> Client example </h2>
  <h3>Output: </h3>
  <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0];              //get id
        var vname = data[1];           //get name
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
        // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
      } 
    });
  }); 

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```